# Implicit differentiation: $x^2y - 2x^3 - y^3 + 1 = 0$

Tags: calculus

Hi I'm stuck on one problem in my study guide. It's the only one with an = 0 at the end of it.

Differentiate:

$x^2y - 2x^3 - y^3 + 1 = 0$

Comment: Are you aware of [implicit functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function) and [implicit differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function#Implicit_differentiation)?

Comment: If the zero is the **only** thing that bothers you, why not move any term you like from the LHS to the RHS (changing the sign, of course)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implicit differentiation:

$$2xy\,dx+x^2\,dy-6x^2\,dx-3y^2\,dy=0\implies (x^2-3y^2)dy=(6x^2-2xy)dx\implies$$

$$y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{6x^2-2xy}{x^2-3y^2}\;,\;\;x\neq\pm\sqrt 3\, y$$

Comment: If you're gonna leave it as an implicit relation anyway, why deal with division and not let it be at the next-to-last step?

Comment: Well @GitGud , that was just to display the well known form of $\,y'\,$ , but the OP is, of course, free to choose to leave it as (s)he wants.

Comment: Got it. +1${}{}$

Comment: Antonio, what made you group (x^2-3y^2) on one side of the = and (6x^2-2xy) on the other? How'd you decide that?

Comment: All the coefficients of $\,dy\,$ here, and all the coefficients of $\,dx\,$ there...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't feel comfortable with messing around with $dx$ and $dy$ like DonAntonio does in his answer, you can also view this simply as an application of the chain rule. Say you have an equation $$
  F(x,y) = 0 \text{.}
$$

If you let $x$ be the independent $y = y(x)$ be the dependent variable, this becomes $$
  F(x, y(x)) = 0
$$
Applying chain rule yields $$\begin{aligned}
  &&F_x + F_yy' &= 0 \\
  \Rightarrow
  &&y' &= -\frac{F_x}{F_y} \quad\text{if $F_y \neq 0$}
\end{aligned}$$
where $F_x$, $F_y$ are the partial derivatives of $F$ with respect to $x$,$y$.

For your problem $F(x,y) = x^2y−2x^3−y^3+1=0$, you get $$\begin{aligned}
  &&F_x &= 2xy - 6x^2 \\
  &&F_y &= x^2 - 3y^2 \\
  \Rightarrow
  &&y' &= -\frac{F_x}{F_y} = \frac{6x^2 - 2xy}{x^2 - 3y^2}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: @amWhy Duh! Thanks for pointing those out!

Comment: You're welcome! ;-)